# Scala unresolved dependencies path - how to parse the error message?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am hot-fixing a package and moving it from Scala2 to Scala3. As part of this process, I am getting the following warning and error when running `sbt compile`:

```
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.
Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          org.wartremover:sbt-wartremover:3.0.4
(sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=3)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException:
Error downloading org.wartremover:sbt
wartremover;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=3:3.0.4
```

I see on [MVN repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wartremover/wartremover) that wartremover version 3.0.4 is available for Scala 3.1.2. I'd love to have a recipe for fixing this where I can parse the error and make sense of it for next steps, a recipe that I can use when I encounter this error in other situations. Since I'm hot-fixing, it might be that there's constraints from other config files that I haven't yet edited, I'm hoping that if that's the case I can learn how to detect such files.

Some questions:

1. Is the SBT version wrong (I have 1.6.2 in my configs but the error mentions 1.0)?
2. Is the Scala version wrong (the error mentions 3 but I have 3.1.2)?

I have the following settings (pasting the ones that seem most relevant)

`build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "3.1.2"
```

`build.properties`:

```
sbt.version=1.6.2
```

`plugins.sbt` (following the [wartremover instructions](https://www.wartremover.org/doc/install-setup.html)):

```
addSbtPlugin("org.wartremover"    % "sbt-wartremover" % "3.0.4")
```

Comment: SBT 1.0 means any 1.x version, this look's okay.

Comment: The Scala 3 version is slightly odd but this shouldn't matter. Do you confirm you did not add it to the library dependencies, right? Only in plugins.sbt?

Comment: Let me know if I'm not answering the question correctly. When I search for `scalaVersion`, every usage is `scalaVersion := "3.1.2"` (in a couple of config files).

Comment: @cgold _"(in a couple of config files)"_ which are those files? I think you are trying to use **Scala 3** in the meta-build, and that won't work.

Comment: Thanks! The configs are "scalac.sbt" and "project/scalac.sbt". Why does using Scala 3 in the meta-build not work?

Comment: Yeah, remove that from `project/scalac.sbt` - it won't work because the meta build only supports `2.12`

Comment: Thanks! I have since learned that the term "meta build" refers to the build instructions in the "project" folder. How do you know that this meta build only supports 2.12?

Comment: I've now figured it out: The Wartremover documentation https://www.wartremover.org/doc/install-setup.html describes that "wartremover 3.x requires Scala 2.12.+. please use wartremover 2.x for Scala 2.11". Thanks for the hints.

Comment: @cgold SBT supports only 2.12 in the meta build for now, that's not related to this specific plugin: all plugins are written in Scala 2.12 (which does not mean they cannot be used in a Scala 3 project).